# How to crop image in freestyle(as user wants) while selecting from image picker in ios

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, crop

can any one help me in cropping image in freestyle as user wants.
I tried the below method, but its cropping image only in square shape.

```
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]  as? UIImage{

            pickImage.image = image

            let imageData:NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickImage.image!, 0.5) as! NSData
            if(imageData != nil){
//             let imageStr1 = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
                let imageStr1 = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.lineLength64Characters)
              imageStr = "data:image/png;base64,\(imageStr1))"



            }


        }

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Please try to answer me with apple default methods, if available.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can pick one of these from here https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=crop

Comment: use this library https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mdimagecroper

Comment: I need in swift not objective-C